# Is it necessary to add the pom.xml file after inserting the jar manually

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring, jar

As I am new to springs I want to know that is it necessary to add a pom.xml file in my eclipse spring project as I have manually added the jars required for the project.

Also please tell me that can I use different jar versions in the same project like spring-core 3.0.1 and spring-bean 3.0.5 like this?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of creating Java projects.

One way (as you did) is to manually add JARs to your project (usually to: WEB-INF/lib) directory, then compile your project etc. The problem with this approach is that it can become complicated to manage manually big number of libraries in your project.

Another option is to use some automated tools (like Maven) for managing your libraries.

So, answering your question - no, you don't need to add pom.xml if you don't use Maven.

Well, as I can tell from my own experience - usually it's better to have same versions of Spring libraries in your project. So, if you use spring-core spring-core 3.0.1 - look for  spring-bean 3.0.1 version. Because otherwise you might experience some problems with different version of libraries...

Comment: It helped me a lot. If you think that my query was relevant please vote for this question.

Comment: also please help me on issue mention in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033791/error-context-initialization-failed-during-server-startup/19042094?noredirect=1#19042094

Answer (score 0):

> Is it necessary to add the pom.xml file after inserting the jar
>   manually?

**No.** it is not necessary add dependency of that jar file  in pom.xml, if you manually add jar file in classpath.

> Also please tell me that can I use different jar versions in the same
>   project like spring-core 3.0.1 and spring-bean 3.0.5 like this?

Every maven dependency have three compulsory parts, like:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
 </dependency>
```

Here, in last version property, you should used your desired version number.

Please note that, **Maven not only add the jar file dependency, but also has a lot more functionality like life cycle of project. (e.g compile, test, deploy and lot more).**

Comment: okay. but please help on the issue mention in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033791/error-context-initialization-failed-during-server-startup/19042094?noredirect=1#19042094

Answer (score 0):

pom.xml is required for building project using Maven. You might import jars manually in eclipse but for building the project in some other build system which supports Maven, you would need pom.xml.

If you are just dealing with eclipse and adding jars manually, you don't need pom.xml. But be sure to add all transitive dependencies as well.

Regarding different versions of different jars of Spring, it would be best to check spring websites. Though if major version matches like (3.0), they should work fine together.

Comment: Please help on the issue mention in the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033791/error-context-initialization-failed-during-server-startup/19042094?noredirect=1#19042094